# Playing song in background on shake

Tags: iphone, ios5, shake

I want the app to start playing songs in background when anybody shakes the device. The song should stop playing when the app enter the foreground. I know we can play songs in background but I dont know how to start playing song on shake when app is in background. I,m new to Iphone so please anyone can help me this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible (as long as we are talking about apps, which will be sold through the App Store), since background-processes are highly limited.

Comment: It means that ios cant detect shake when app is in background

Comment: Actually yes, if you want to be able to post it to the iOS App Store you're not able to use such types of background activities. You could've figure it out if you read the documentation:http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html . Of course, it's technically possible…